# How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

How can I find which command is bound to a give keyboard shortcut? I remember playing with my keyboard shortcuts recently in different places: System/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts, "gnome-keyboard-properties" and Compiz. Is there a central place where all those shortcuts are kept or do I have to remember all the places where I set a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no central place.  Any application can grab certain keys and use them as shortcuts, and it's up to that application to choose a configuration method.  GNOME applications typically use gconf.  Compiz and Metacity even share the gconf keys -- those are the shortcuts you can see in gnome-keybinding-properties.

Answer (score 3):

The best place I've found is to use gconf. Hit F2 for a run box and type in gconf-editor, then browse to apps > metacity > global_keybindings. You can also set up custom commands in the keybinding_commands section and call them up there. Example:
For keybinding command command_1 I put in "gnome-screensaver-command --activate" without the quotes.
Then for global keybinding run_command_1 I put in "s" also without quotes. Whenever I use that key command I activate the screensaver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems no more than a less friendly interface for "gnome-keybinding-properties".

Comment: There's no apps > metacity on my system (Xubunti 17.10). There's only blueman and gconf-editor under apps.

Comment: As @Bulletmagnet indicates, modern Ubuntu doesn't seem to have this. `apps > metacity` isn't present in Ubuntu 18.04