# Command to mute and unmute a microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, alsa

During voice / video conversations I would like to mute/unmute the microphone without having to go through all these steps each time:

- Sound indicator, Sound preferences, Select Input, Mute or unmute the microphone.

I'm looking for either:

- an application that can do this from the command line,
- a way I can assign a keyboard shortcut that can mute/unmute the microphone

Comment: If you use Empathy for voice chat, it has a mute button built-in (that works with Google Talk at least, Skype isn't supported yet).

Comment: I'm looking for something that can be made to run through a shortcut, similar to the main volume mute/unmute laptop toggle button.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** then **Keyboard** and click **Shortcuts** then **Custom Shortcuts**:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Click on **Add**

[image: Custom shortcut]

Fill in:

```
Toggle Microphone
```

and

```
amixer set Capture toggle
```

For USB webcams you need to chose the device (`-c 1`), or maybe another number.

```
amixer -c 1 sset Mic toggle
```

Click **Apply** and then associate a new key with this command (e.g. the <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> key).

Comment: Works this with recent releases? Thank you.

Comment: It does work; thanks to Lucian. I have an "Audio mute" key on my laptop, I mapped it to shift+Audio mute, which is very easy to remember :)

Comment: The command `amixer set Mic toggle` (not `Capture`) works for me in terminal but any assigned keyboard shortcut doesn't actually seem to run.  I've tried `ctrl+Audio Mute` but also `ctrl+M` (captured by keyboard key presses)

Comment: Confirmed, this works with Ubuntu 16.10 as well.

Comment: On MATE the menus for adding the keybinding are a little different, but it works in the same way. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to use ``amixer scontrols`` to find the control to use and type it out fully with ``amixer set 'Capture',1 toggle``

Answer (score 22):

You can mute the microphone with

```
amixer set Capture nocap
```

and unmute the microphone with

```
amixer set Capture cap
```

Comment: that worked great with raspberry pi, except you substitute Mic for Capture

Answer (score 16):

I switch between a USB webcam/mic and my internal mic and the other solutions typically work on the "default" device which is often not the device I'm actively using so I wrote this to mute *all* microphones

```
pacmd list-sources | \
        grep -oP 'index: \d+' | \
        awk '{ print $2 }' | \
        xargs -I{} pactl set-source-mute {} toggle \
        && pacmd list-sources | \
        grep -oP 'muted: (?:yes|no)'
```

Comment: I like this atomic approach. Consider using something like `'index: \d?\d'` to account for double-digit source indices.

Comment: `'index: \d+'` is the more appropriate regexp, but yeah that works :)

Answer (score 14):

```
amixer set Capture toggle && amixer get Capture | grep '\[off\]' && notify-send "MIC switched OFF" || notify-send "MIC switched ON"
```

Comment: I like the way in which you combine grep and notifications: Super Neat =)

Answer (score 11):

Simply mute/unmute with this command:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Capture toggle
```

You can also add notification to make sure it's on or off, as per vladimirich [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/576507/424528) to the same question

```
amixer -D pulse sset Capture toggle && amixer get Capture | grep '\[off\]' && notify-send "MIC switched OFF" || notify-send "MIC switched ON"
```

Inspired by Mark Rooney's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/109840/424528) on muting/unmuting sound.

Comment: This actually works for me on Ubuntu 16.04. `-q` can be skipped.

Comment: ``bindsym XF86AudioMicMute exec --no-startup-id amixer -D pulse sset Capture toggle`` for ``i3wm``

Comment: This command works for me in Pop_OS! 19.10 (which is based on Ubuntu 19.10). One can explicitly disable microphone capture with the command `amixer --device pulse sset Capture nocap` and turn the volume of capturing to 0% simultaneously with the command `amixer --device pulse sset Capture nocap 0%`.

Answer (score 7):

On 20.04, I see option to set a shortcut for the same under `Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Sound and Media`.

[image]

There is no default key assigned though.

Comment: The same found in gnome 3.38.5 (debian 11).

Answer (score 6):

`pacmd` is the command line interface to PulseAudio (the sound subsystem used in recent releases). I don't know what the exact command is you'd need but I think you'd want to play with the `set-sink-input-mute` function.

`pacmd` is interactive when run without instructions so you have a good opportunity to play around with it and convert that into a one-line function for toggling mute.

Comment: pacmd is only interactive if you don't give it any commands. I used `pacmd list-sources` to get a list of inputs and outputs. Under index 2 I had an input devide. (based on its name) Then you can run `pacmd set-source-mute 2 1` to mute. Last parameter is a boolean for mute state. 0 or false for unmute and 1 or true for mute.

Comment: Here is a one-liner to toggle, instead of set the state: `pacmd list-sources | grep -e 'index' -e 'muted:' | sed -n -e '/index: 5/,$p' | head -n2 | tail -n1 | grep yes && pacmd set-source-mute 5 0 || pacmd set-source-mute 5 1`. Note that the index occurs in three places, so you need to change those.

Answer (score 6):

the gnome-shell extension [nothing to say](https://github.com/wbolster/nothing-to-say), which can be installed from [its extensions.gnome.org page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1113/nothing-to-say/), provides a microphone icon, mouse and keyboard control, and walkie-talkie style push-to-talk.

Answer (score 5):

To toggle mute of default microphone in pulseaudio:

1. Make sure that you have `pacmd` (from `pulseaudio-utils` package) and `notify-send` (from `libnotify-bin`).
2. Use this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

pacmd list-sources | awk '\
BEGIN {default_found=0;}

/^[\t ]*\*/ {default_found=1;}

/^[\t ]*name:/ {
    if (default_found) {
        name=$2;
        gsub("[<>]", "", name);
    }
}

/^[\t ]*muted:/ {
    if (default_found) {
        if ($2=="yes") {
            mute=0;
            icon="microphone-sensitivity-medium";
            status="unmuted"
        } else {
            mute=1;
            icon="microphone-sensitivity-muted";
            status="muted"
        }
        system("pacmd set-source-mute " name " " mute);
        system("notify-send --expire-time 1000 --icon " icon " Microphone: " status);
        exit;
    }
}

/^[\t ]*index:/{if (default_found) exit;}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can mute with:

```
/usr/bin/amixer -q -c 0 sset 'Master',0 mute
```

Unmute:

```
/usr/bin/amixer -q -c 0 sset 'Master',0 unmute
```

You just need to replace 'Master' with the appropriate mixer name, on the terminal use "amixer" to get a list of mixer devices.

About setting the keyboard shortcut check the answers for [How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4750/how-can-i-find-which-command-is-bound-to-a-given-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: These mute the sound from my speakers, not the microphone, but thanks.

Comment: You just need to replace 'Master' with the appropriate mixer name, on the terminal use "amixer" to get a list of mixer devices.

Comment: This seems to work:
# amixer set Capture toggle

Comment: Can you edit your response (I don't have the necessary karma) to include this answer so I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the response of[Lucian Adrian Grijincu](https://askubuntu.com/users/3026/lucian-adrian-grijincu) and [vladimirich](https://askubuntu.com/users/371162/vladimirich)

Add the display of a message by enabling/disabling the microphone.

Run multiple commands on the shortcut command:

```
$ sh -c "amixer set Capture toggle ; amixer get Capture | \
     grep '\[off\]' && notify-send 'MIC switched OFF' || notify-send 'MIC switched ON'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer above https://askubuntu.com/a/337662/106182

I like to create my own `terminal` stupid shortcuts. So to configrure `m` = mute; `mm` = unmute

I added this to `./.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc
# 
alias m="amixer set Capture nocap"
alias mm="amixer set Capture cap"
```

**update**

interesting enough, yesterday I've re-enable autostart of "Screen Locker (Launch screen locker program) in the `menu> sessions and startup > Application Autostart` and now my hardware mute button start working (after restart) I have no idea why (XFCE Xubuntu 18.08)

I'm still keeping those terminal shortcuts but just wanted to point out

Comment: It's silly that it's not on/off but cap/nocap and that it's not documented or discoverable. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for toggling a selected audio source only using CLI (command line interface) only:

1. Get list of possible sound cards in the system:

   `pacmd list-sources | grep card:`

   Example:

   `card: 0 <alsa_card.usb-Microsoft_Microsoft___LifeCam_HD-5000-02>`

   `card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>`
2. Select some way to identify the correct card. If you trust that your configuration does not change, you can use card number and simply run (e.g. if you want to control the card 1):

   `pactl set-source-mute 1 toggle`

   However, if you instead want to prepare for a case where e.g. your USB connected source is not always connected and you only want to mute that, you can use some way to detect it from the above output. Let's say you want to control the LifeCam HD-5000 only. Then you could do it like this:

   `pacmd list-sources | grep -P "card: \d+ <[^>]*LifeCam_HD-5000[^>]*>" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -rn1 -I_ pactl set-source-mute _ toggle`

   This queries all audio sources from PulseAudio, extracts card rows that have `LifeCam_HD-5000` as part of their name, uses `awk` to extract the second part of the row to get the card number and passes it to `pactl` to toggle correct source muting using `xargs` to put the number in correct position in the command. The `-rn1` flag tells xargs to do nothing if the card number couldn't be found.

   If you need to know the mute status for some scripting, you can do

   `pacmd dump | grep -P 'set-source-mute [^ ]*LifeCam_HD-5000' | awk '{print $3}'`

   which will emit `yes` (muted) or `no` (not muted).

Answer (score 0):

Using [answer of vladimirich](https://askubuntu.com/a/576507/1047801) I created a script, because we can't execute multiple commands in a hotkey entry.

- so I made a script with the line:

  ```
  amixer set Capture toggle && amixer get Capture | grep '\[off\]' && notify-send "MIC switched OFF" || notify-send "MIC switched ON"
  ```
- put it in a `.sh` file
- and call it in the hotkey command with `sh <path to script.sh>`.

Works like a charm.