# Command  to unmute and maximize volume?

Tags: sound, command-line, alsa

I need to mute/unmute from the command line.
I found out that I can do it with:

```
amixer sset Master mute
amixer sset Master unmute
```

the problem is that the command for unmute is not working (as described also in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils/+bug/878986)

My question is: is there another way to obtain the same result, taken that amixer is not working?

Furthermore, if I set manually the volume to minimum and then call

```
amixer sset Master 100%
```

the volume increases but doesn't switch to maximum, even if the stdout tells:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
Limits: Playback 0 - 31
Mono:
Front Left: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Front Right: Playback 31 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly for me.  I don't user 'Master', however.  Have you tried setting different controls?  Does it work if you use Front vs Master?  Open alsamixer to view which options you have.

Comment: I tried also with 'Speaker' and 'Headphone' but same result, I also tried on other pc and laptop and still the same result: mute works, unmute doesn't

Comment: Can you try `amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute` in a terminal and see if it works.

Comment: It works only if I did not mute from the command line but from the gui (11.10). If I mute from the command line then I cannot unmute.

Comment: if I do "amixer -c 0 set Master playback 0% mute" and "amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute" it works!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following commands in a terminal

```
amixer -c 0 set Master playback 0% mute
amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute
```

This should ensure all outputs are controlled. It's likely with your posted commands the reason the volume is not 100% is that the amixer does not release all outputs eg headphones or any other sound outputs at the same time.

Comment: why do you mute, before unmuting?

Answer (score 16):

Even better is this one, unmute all audio devices. 
and set volume to 70%

```
for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do amixer cset "${x}" on ; done


for x in `amixer controls  | grep layback` ; do amixer cset "${x}" 70% ; done
```

in the example above the HDMI and optical isn't unmutted..

Comment: Thanks. The commands in other answers, such as 'amixer -c 0 set Master playback 100% unmute' or 'amixer set Master unmute' did not work for me (even if I mute via 'amixer set Master mute').

Answer (score 5):

Get all sounds sources, get their names, form a command line with amixer and execute it

```
amixer scontrols | grep -oE "'.*'" | awk -F\' \
 '{print "amixer -c 0 set \""$2"\" unmute 100"}' | sh
```

Unmutes all audio devices and sets their volume to max.

Have a great one, Mike

Comment: This one works good for me, the only thing left unmentioned is that this sets `PCM` to a hard value of `100` out of a ceiling `255`, so the volume will be a little quiet. You can further adjust this with `amixer -c 0 set PCM 100%`. (@Kubuntu 18.04/awesomewm)

Answer (score 2):

Mark Rooney's solution did not work for me, but I was able to work around this by explicitly unmuting all of the channels.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in Master Headphone PCM Front Surround Center LFE Side; do
    amixer -c 0 set "$i" playback unmute
done &>/dev/null
```

I got the channel names but running `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you need to know your different card numbers from

```
alsamixer
```

select cards from F6 and note the card number that has Master option

If you use headphones, then we change both Master and Headphone

```
amixer -c 1 set Master toggle && amixer -c 1 set Headphone toggle
```

where -c specifies the card number, 1 in this command.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using doesn't work for me either, but try these. They work for me.

```
amixer set Master 0
amixer set Master 100
```

Comment: with your commands the volume is lowered/raised but not to minimum/maximum as I would need

Comment: This solution won't raise the volume  sufficiently. remember that the ranges for the volume control is `0` to `65536`. `amixer set Master 65536` will set the volume to maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from **Mark Rooney** didn't help me because that command gave me an error (my sound card has number 1):

```
amixer: Mixer attach hw:1 error: Invalid argument
```

So I tried

```
amixer set Master 100 unmute
```

and it worked perfectly for currently selected sound card. You can also mute it using

```
amixer set Master 0 mute
```