# Mute a microphone with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microphone

I'm using [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12100/keyboard-shortcut-command-to-mute-unmute-microphone) to mute the microphone in Ubuntu 13.04, however I'm missing a **visual representation** that the action has taken  place and is currently in action.

Is it possible to improve this method, or use another method, to have my microphone muted and know for sure that this has happened? A microphone indicator would be enough, probably.

Comment: I found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/12/ubuntu-notify-send/) how to send notifications. But I did not get it to work wit a shortcut. In the terminal `amixer set Capture toggle && notify-send 'microphone toggled'` worked. maybe a start for you or someone els to figure something out...

Comment: That's a nice find, @Wouter! It works from terminal, but doesn't work as a keyboard shortcut, for some reason. Hopefully someone can solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved it!

I've created two shell files:

**`mute_mic.sh:`**

```
killall notify-osd;
amixer set Capture nocap && notify-send 'Microphone ! DISABLED !'
```

**`unmute_mic.sh:`**

```
killall notify-osd;
amixer set Capture cap && notify-send 'Microphone ! ENABLED !'
```

Then I've simply assigned to run those two files on my desired keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks to @Wouter for finding the `notify-send` command!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using gnome-shell, the gnome-shell extension [nothing to say](https://github.com/wbolster/nothing-to-say), which can be installed from [its extensions.gnome.org page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1113/nothing-to-say/), provides a microphone icon, mouse and keyboard control, and walkie-talkie style push-to-talk.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux desktops already react to a special *mute microphone* key (that on notebooks often is accessible via some <kbd>Fn</kbd> + *function key* combination, along with volume up/down/mute). If you don't have such a key, you can map a free key to it.

My keyboard has a set of multimedia keys; I used `xev` to find out the keycode of one (`163`), and then remapped that to the `XF86AudioMicMute` target. Put the mapping in `~/.Xmodmap` and activate via `$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`:

```
! Map the Mail special key from my MS Natural Keyboard Pro to microphone mute.
keycode 163 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute
```

In GNOME and Unity, the toggling of the mute state will be indicated by a big icon overlay in the middle the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For a more recent answer in Ubuntu 20.04: open Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts and search for "Microphone mute/unmute" in the list. You can then assign the shortcut you want.