# How do I turn off the ctrl-shift-R keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4750/how-can-i-find-which-command-is-bound-to-a-given-keyboard-shortcut)

As an eclipse user ctrl-shift-R is a pretty important shortcut for me.

Lately in ubuntu however, something has overriden this shortcut. When I type ctrl-shift-R all keyboard input is frozen until I press esc. It's not eclipse because I get the same effect in any application.

How can I find out what is listening to this shortcut and turn it off?

I checked under keyboard settings but it wasn't listed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: This forces a page reload in Firefox. Do you have Firefox open or installed?

Comment: Did you take a look at [How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4750/how-can-i-find-which-command-is-bound-to-a-given-keyboard-shortcut)