# terminal commands for all default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I want to know which terminal command is performed when I do a keyboard shortcut.

In settings, I can change the default shortcuts but can't see which terminal command is performed for that.

Is there any way to see the terminal commands performed behind those keyboard shortcuts??

Comment: I don't think that is possible, see for example (probably a duplicate) [How can I find which command is bound to a given keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4750).

Comment: It is also not so that pressing a keyboard shortcut necessarily involves launching a terminal command. It is how it works for your custom shortcuts, and probably for some of the default shortcuts that launch applications, but not for shortcuts that for example maximize windows, etc. Maybe you want to provide examples to clarify what you are looking for and what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: actually, I made an application with which I can execute the terminal commands from my mobile phone. So I was thinking that maybe I can perform the keyboard shortcuts from my mobile if I know the right terminal commands for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I wanted to perform keyboard shortcuts operations from my terminal

So, I guess I got some tool for that  `xdotool` solved my problem.